# How to send e-mail from within a Win8 Metro App

Tags: c#, email, windows-8, charms-bar

I am developing a Windows8 Metro App using c# xaml and I have to send the app link as an e-mail to someone using the share contract.

What I have tried is 
                  private void RegisterForShare()
             {
             DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();

```
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareLinkHandler);
          }

     private void ShareLinkHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)         {

       DataRequest request = e.Request; 
       request.Data.Properties.Title = "Sharing My Link";
       request.Data.Properties.Description = "Add a link (URI) to share";

       var _Uri = new Uri("https://login.live.com/");
        Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(_Uri);
   }
```

And also,

```
        void App_QuerySubmitted(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        App.SettingsFlyout.Equals(args.Request, ApplicationExecutionState.Running);

    }
```

But it works in a way where the specified link just opens and not a feature where the email of the link could be sent to soemone.

Any suggestions or solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the share charm to let the user sent text if you want to the user to definitely send email (as opposed to Twitter / Facebook) then you should use the mailto protocol.

```
await Launcher.LaunchUri(new Uri("mailto://test@address.com?subject=email"));
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel..! This already works. But is there any way to mail content-specific data? Say, any selected item from an itemDetailPage?

Comment: You can add content to the email by appending &body=itemDetailGoesHere

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood! I mean, when a user clicks an item and clicks 'share', that particular item should be mailed to him! Is this possiblE?

Comment: What I have tried now is the following, but it does not work!  `ListView items = new ListView();
                if (items.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {
                    var item = "Selected Item: " + items.SelectedItem;
                    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Item Selection";
                    request.Data.SetText(item);
                }
                else 
                {
                    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Select an item to share!";
                }`

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in API for sending emails. Microsoft recommend to use share charm to send the email. Though if you want to send email via you need to go for commercial library called [Mail.dll](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store)

Comment: I just modified the code a little `void dataTransferManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            AoO.SettingsFlyout.Equals(args.Request, ApplicationExecutionState.Running);

        }` and ` DataRequest request = e.Request;  request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://"));` and it works fine..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=recipient@example.com&subject=Your subject&body=Your text");     
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```